# Comparing pairs of conditions

Tags: javascript, if-statement, comparison, conditional-statements

Is there a simple way to compare pairs of conditions without nesting if/else statements? In other words, how would one go about combining the following two comparisons into a single comparison?

`(x >= 6 && y <= 5)`, `(y >= 6 && x <= 5)`

What I'd like to do is something like this:

`if ((x >= 6 && y <= 5) || (y >= 6 && x <=5)) // do this`

I know you can accomplish this like so:

```
if (x >= 6) {
  if (y <= 5)
} else {
  if (y >= 6)
}
```

But the issue with this method is that I'd like to execute the same block of code for each circumstance. I know I can achieve this without repeating code by doing the following:

```
if (x >= 6) {
  if (y <= 5) doThis();
} else {
  if (y >= 6) doThis();
}
```

However, that all seems verbose. Is there a better way??

Comment: Are `x` and `y` integers?

Comment: @ConnorsFan variable integers

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since `x` and `y` are integers, you can combine the two comparisons with:

```
if (x >= 6 === y <= 5) {
    ...
}
```

That condition will be true if both sides are true or if they are both false.

---

Here is an explanation for this answer.

1. The initial problem is to simplify this condition:

```
(x >= 6 && y <= 5) || (x <= 5 && y >= 6)
```

2. For integers, `x <= 5` is the opposite of `x >= 6` (and the equivalent applies to y); therefore we can write the condition as:

```
(x >= 6 && y <= 5) || (!(x >= 6) && !(y <= 5))
```

3. We can define boolean variables to make it clear:

```
let cond1 = x >= 6;
let cond2 = y <= 5;

(cond1 && cond2) || (!cond1 && !cond2)
```

4. Which can also be written as follows:

```
(cond1 === true && cond2 === true) || (cond1 === false && cond2 === false)
```

5. Since `true` and `false` are the only possible values, the previous line is equivalent to

```
(cond1 === cond2)
```

6. Putting back the original expressions for the variables:

```
((x >= 6) === (y <= 5))
```

7. Since the operators `>=` and `<=` have [higher precedence](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Operator_Precedence) than `===`, the inner parentheses can be removed:

```
(x >= 6 === y <= 5)
```

Comment: very interesting. i've never seen something like that before. is there a name for it?

Comment: As mentioned by @MooingDuck in a comment to Nina's answer, it is similar to what the XOR operator does; in fact it is the opposite. The [XOR operator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exclusive_or) returns true if the two boolean values are opposite (one true, one false), and returns false if they are the same. As far as I know, the XOR operator in Javascript (`^`) is used as a [bitwise operator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bitwise_operation), not really as a logical operator.

Comment: what do you expect with triple condition without parenthesis? by the way, assuming the both conditions are grouped with parenthesis like `(x >= 6) === (y <= 5)`, you get the area of the `false` Evaluation as well as result, which is definitely not the same as the original given comparisons.

Comment: @NinaScholz - Since `>=` and `<=` have [higher precedence](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Operator_Precedence) than `===`, parentheses are not needed. What do you mean by getting the area of the false? If the result was the opposite of the original comparison, he could replace `===` with `!==`, but that does not seem to be the case here.

Comment: The logic is bad in this answer. this will produce false positives because you are evaluating on three Booleans. 
let x = 4;
let y= 6;
if (x >= 6 === y <= 5) {
   console.log(x)
    console.log(y)
} what you will get is false === false in this case which will evaluate to true. even though both conditions fail. @NinaScholz is right because the space of possibilities will result in false positives because of the tri Boolean  evalution space

Comment: @Arrow - Surprising how people don't understand such a simple answer. This answer expresses the full condition `(x >= 6 && y <= 5) || (y >= 6 && x <=5)` as required in the question. In your example, If x = 4 and y = 6, the final result should be `true`. As I mentioned in the answer, the final result is `true` if both sides are `true` or if they are both `false`. And that is the way it should be.

Comment: @ConnorsFan I didn't down vote your answer, but are you saying that this will work for all similarly nested conditions? It seems strange because nested conditions have an execution order, can you put some working examples in your code to clarify?

Comment: @Arrow - My answer was for the specific case stated in the question. It works because the conditions on each side of the OR are exact opposites (given that x and y are integers).

Comment: @ConnorsFan I'm not going make an assumption about your answer. It seems interesting if you happen to be right. However, you should provide some consistency, no matter how domain specific. As it stands your answer seems like a one-off if it works for the asker. However, that's a false positive. and that is worse than no answer at all. You will be leading people astray.

Comment: @Arrow - The OP wanted to simplify his expression and I provided an answer that does just that. You and NinaScholz both said that it did not work in that specific case, and you were wrong.

Comment: @ConnorsFan turns out you are correct  "if and only if x and y are integers. The original expression leaves the gap between 5 and 6 as false, and xor doesn't have any gap"

Comment: @Arrow - Yes. That is why I asked Anthony to confirm that they were integers. He could have written his conditions as `x <= 5` and `x > 5` to eliminate any doubt.

Comment: @Arrow - I thought you didn't downvote my answer. :-) What should I edit?

Comment: I did after your last comment yesterday :)

Comment: You should elaborate!!! put more details so others do not make the same mistake when looking at your answer :)

Comment: @Arrow - I added an explanation to my answer.

Comment: just a hint, you could use `x <= 5 === y >= 6` as well.